# Appending data to a file during a power loss

Tags: java

I am writing a `byte[]` to a file using `Files.write(filePath, data, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`

What happens to the file when the power goes out or the JVM crashes during the write process? Does it corrupt the data that is currently written to the file, or even the file entirely?

Background: I am running a data recording application on a Raspberry Pi and the method to turn it off is unplugging it.

What do you think or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: *"during a power loss"* - tbh, any **unflushed** data will be gone. you should invest on backup power, UPS or something.

Comment: As Bagus Tesa said any unflushed data will be gone. What happens to the rest really depends on the exact OS, filesystem and settings you are using. Some filesystems are built for reliability as the primary goal and will ensure that only consistent views are possible, others might reorder writes and have "nonsense" results (such as some blocks of data missing/zeroed and further blocks being written correctly).

Comment: maybe we should attack the problem from different angle. like, *"can we detect the shutdown signal?"* if yes, we should shutdown the device properly (if possible). then, to prevent total power loss we should make it have some batteries or something. to be considered is to have the data not on the edge device (raspberry pi) itself but rather send them somewhere with better fault protection.

Comment: Data "corruption" would be dependent on the type of data.  Possibly set up a writing process that will append the data in buffered segments; as to provide some sort of mechanism for retrieving incomplete data, during a corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the power goes out or the JVM crashes during a write operation, it's possible that the data being written will be corrupted.

Typical scenarios are:

1. Partial Write: If the power goes out during a write operation, it's possible that only a portion of the bytes in your byte array got written to the disk. This means that the file may contain some new data, but not all of the new data.
2. Corruption: In some cases, a sudden power loss or system crash can result in the corruption of the file. This can happen if the system was in the middle of updating file metadata (like location of data blocks, file size, etc.) when the power loss occurred. However, such cases are quite rare with modern file systems.

For your use-case, you might want to consider the following:

1. Use a Database: If you're dealing with a lot of data, consider using a database system that is designed to handle power failures and crashes. SQLite could be a good choice for a Raspberry Pi system as it is a very lightweight database.

```java
try {
    // Connect to the SQLite database
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database_path");

    // Create a binary blob and write data to it
    String sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (blob_column) VALUES (?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstmt.setBytes(1, bytes);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2. Flush and Sync: To make sure your write operations are immediately reflected in the file, you can flush the output stream and then sync the changes to the disk. This minimizes the amount of data that can be lost in the event of a power outage. However, keep in mind that this can impact your application's performance due to more frequent disk I/O operations.

```java
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file_path")) {
    out.write(bytes);
    out.getFD().sync();  // This forces the output bytes to be written to disk
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

3. Write to a Temporary File First: Another approach is to first write the data to a temporary file. Once the write operation is complete, you can then rename the temporary file to the final file. This ensures that you always have a complete version of the data from before the write operation started. If a power loss happens during the write, you might lose the new data but you'll still have the old data.

```java
try {
    // Write data to a temporary file
    Path tempPath = Paths.get("temp_file_path");
    Files.write(tempPath, bytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);

    // Rename the temporary file to the final file
    Path finalPath = Paths.get("final_file_path");
    Files.move(tempPath, finalPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the power goes out or JVM crashes during write process, there is a risk of data corruption. The behavior depends on various factors, such as the underlying operating system and file system.

In general, when you use `Files.write` with the `CREATE` and `APPEND` options, it will create a new file if it doesn't exist and append the provided data to the file if it already exists. If the write process gets interrupted due to a power outage or JVM crash, the file might be left in an inconsistent state.